# Navigating to upper-level list element in unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm trying to navigate through an unordered list and having trouble making it work fully.

There are 4 buttons - <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, and <kbd>Right</kbd>. Navigating with <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> will correctly take you to the previous or next `<li>` (vertically) on that level, if one exists. Navigating <kbd>Right</kbd> will take you to the first list item inside the (down a level) in that `<ul>`, if an `<ul>` exists.

The left button should basically reverse that order (go up a level), but it doesn't.

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .btn { margin: 10px; padding: 10px; background-color: #999; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; }
    .current > span { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left btn">Left</div>        
<div class="right btn">Right</div>      
<div class="up btn">Up</div>        
<div class="down btn">Down</div>

<ul id="demo01">
    <li class="current"><span>one</span></li>
    <li><span>two</span></li>
    <li><span>three</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>four</span></li>
            <li><span>five</span></li>
            <li><span>six</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>seven</span></li>
                    <li><span>eight</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>nine</span></li>
</ul>
```

**JS / JQuery**

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click','.right', function() {
        var current = $('#demo01 li.current');
        if(current.has("ul").length){
            right = current.find('li').first();
            current.removeClass('current');
            right.addClass('current');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click','.left', function() {
        var current = $('#demo01 li.current');
        if( current.parent.has('ul').length) {
            left = current.parent('ul li');
            current.removeClass('current');
            left.addClass('current');
        }           
    });

    $(document).on('click','.up', function() {
        var current = $('#demo01 li.current');
        if( current.prev('li').length) {
            up = current.prev('li');
            current.removeClass('current');
            up.addClass('current');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click','.down', function() {
        var current = $('#demo01 li.current');
        if( current.next('li').length) {
            down = current.next('li');
            current.removeClass('current');
            down.addClass('current');
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

**Current level of functionality:**

Using the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> buttons, you can succesfully navigate to "eight". The expectation is that when you click the <kbd>Left</kbd> button, to go back to the top, you'd go to "six" (not "four"), then "three" (not "one"). Right now, I'm getting nothing.

I thought using `parent()` jQuery function would be the way to go, but I must be writing it incorrectly.

I suppose each time I click through, I could add/remove a class ("last-visit"), and when "returning" do a find on that. I'd like to first know what I'm doing wrong with the code I've written.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: i can't get any buttons to work : http://jsfiddle.net/go0yjoae/

Comment: @DinoMyte You're missing a `}` near the end. See http://jsfiddle.net/gqxtrLgj/.

Comment: you were missing the () on the .parent() http://jsfiddle.net/kennygfunk/35m67tjq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to navigate to the `li` which parent to `ul` for 4,5,6 spans

```
 $(document).on('click','.left', function() {
        var current = $('#demo01 li.current');
        if(current.parent().parent().closest("li").length) 
        {
            left = current.parent().parent().closest("li");            
            current.removeClass('current');
            left.addClass('current');
        }           
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/go0yjoae/1/

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I see now that I didn't go far enough with the parent() function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change:

```
if( current.parent.has('ul').length) {
```

to:

```
if( current.parent().has('ul').length) {
```

`parent` is not a property of the `current` object. It is the function `parent()`.

---

You also need to change this line:

```
left = current.parent('ul li');
```

to:

```
left = current.parents('li');
```

```
left = current.parent('ul').parent('li'); // params are optional
```

Your above is selecting a *direct (one-level up) ancestor* `ul` and its interior `li` (which is the current `current` element). Then, it makes it not `current`. Therefore, this does not work.

The modified line <strike>looks for *any* ancestors (can be more than one level up)</strike> goes up *two levels* to get to the correct `<li>` element.

See a working example at [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/gqxtrLgj/4/).

**EDIT** See the comment below. This is more correct now.

Comment: current.parent().has('li') would give you all the li's in the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/gqxtrLgj/3/

Comment: @DinoMyte Oops Sorry I'll fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried several parent() combinations, but didn't try your solution. I also forgot to specify in my question that once you navigate back (left) to the top level, you shouldn't be able to go any further. DinoMyte's solution accomplished that goal. I'm going to keep your solution in mind also.